# error: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'invalid sender'}

Tags: transactions, tokens, web3.py, bsc, smart-contract

I have my smart contract deployed on BSC Testnet:

https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x01AbBD3c43d447dA73CDee8d138697Df36f785d2

If I connect my Metamask on bscscan, I can use all the write contract methods, however, when I try to invoke methods using Python, I run into the problem of getting error: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'invalid sender'}, when sending the transaction. Here is my code sample:

```
import json

from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/'))
web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

account_from = {
    'private_key': 'My Private key',
    'address': '0x21Ba7305d6322cD215378D487FfB9C83C42dB82F',
}

contract_address = '0x01AbBD3c43d447dA73CDee8d138697Df36f785d2'

f = open('abi.json',)

abi_file = json.load(f)
abi = abi_file['abi']

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)

mint_tx = contract.functions.mintOneNft(Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x46165Fb8A31ab3098BD730876546107271Ced745')).buildTransaction(
    {
        'from': account_from['address'],
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account_from['address']),
    }
)

tx_create = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(mint_tx, account_from['private_key'])

tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(tx_create.rawTransaction)
```

Cannot figure out what the problem is here, everything seems pretty straight forward. Help with how to fix it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I know this is a silly question - but have you verified that the private key is for the correct account?

Comment: Yeah, checked with web3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(account_from['private_key']), got my account address, seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that web3py library has some problems, when working with BSC.

The problem was that BSC requires `gasPrice` included into transaction. So, after modifying the code as follow:

```
mint_tx = contract.functions.mintOneNft(Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x46165Fb8A31ab3098BD730876546107271Ced745')).buildTransaction(
    {
        'from': account_from['address'],
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account_from['address']),
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('20', 'gwei'),
    }
)
```

Everything seems to work properly

Comment: "invalid sender" error has nothing to do with gas prices, it means you are using invalid chainID when signing the transaction

Comment: I suppose you just cross-pasted incorrect network ID somewhere in your code